# Python: Uploading an XML file to a MySQL database

Tags: python, mysql, lxml

I want to use Python to upload a large xml file to MySQL database. I can use lxml to parse it and then upload the records to MySQL one by one. But I just wanted to find out if there is some library that can make it easier.

Answer (score 0):

There is [xml2sql](http://gnosis.cx/download/sql/xml2sql.py), which I haven't tested for myself. You can give it a try. But I'd prefer to write a custom importer/exporter using lxml (for speed), and considering the fact that your xml is large, maybe storing it as a blob is a good idea..

Comment: storing xml like a blob in an sql database? You should be downvoted just for suggesting such nonsense. If you have structured data, you want to keep structured data, and the sense of putting it on a database is having ways to deal with more of it, and performing queries on it.

Comment: This is the reason why I said "maybe". Of course, if he wants queries on data, storing as blob is foolish. But if for example he has graph data, it "might" be appropriate. It's totally application dependent..